# Construct generator matrix given generator polynomial?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

How would I take a generator polynomial and construct a generator matrix out of it for a cyclic code?

For example, I have a cyclic code in:

$R_{15}=GF(2)[x] / \langle x^{15} + 1\rangle$

This is given by the generator polynomial:

$g(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$

So, the length is 15 and the dimension is 15 - 8 = 7.
How would I go about constructing a generator matrix from that?

Should be a k x n matrix which is 7 x 15 correct?

$G = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

That is what I come up with, just wondering if this is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Looks good to me. As a final check (that $g(x)$ is, indeed, a valid generator polynomial) you can verify that the next cyclic shift, i.e. $100000011101000$, is a linear combination of the earlier ones. Unless I made a mistake this is the sum of rows 1,2 and 4, so this checks out. The point of this was to give yet another verification for the claim that $g(x)\mid x^{15}+1$. If you are confident, then this was unnecessary :-)

Comment: TeX-pointer: to get a subscript/superscript consisting of several characters to be typeset correctly you need to wrap it with curly braces. So for example `e^{-x^2/2}` yields $e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: Thank you! Was trying to figure out how to do that. And thanks for the tips on how to verify via cyclic shifts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. The rows of $G$ correspond to the generator polynomial (expressed as a binary $n-$tuple) with all its (non cyclical) $k$ shifts, which correspond to the "canonical" input messages $u_0=(1,0,0,0 \cdots) \equiv 1$, $u_1=(0,1,0,0 \cdots) \equiv x $, $u_2=(0,0,1,0 \cdots) \equiv x^2 $, and so on.

This is the generator for the standard (non-systematic) cyclic code. If you instead want to build a systematic cyclic code, that's a different story.

Comment: Thanks! This got me thinking, is it easy to get a parity check polynomial from the generator polynomial?? (If it's too long of an answer, I'll ask another question after doing some more digging).

Comment: For $g(x)$ to be a generator polinomial, it must be a factor of $x^n+1$, hence you can write $h(x) =(x^n+1)/g(x)$. $h(x)$ is the parity check polynomial.

Comment: By $x^n +1$ do you mean $x^{15} + 1$ ? Do people usually leave the check polynomial in fraction form like that?

Comment: No, you compute it - actually when you factor $x^n+1$ to find a suitable $g(x)$ you also get $h(x)$ : $x^{15}+1=g(x) h(x)$

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks!